# Redirected DNS to another DNS server

Tags: windows, domain-name-system

I am using Windows Server 2012, at my workplace I have done setup of a DNS server in a domain controller. Because I'm using virtual desktops.

The question is, when I configure the rest of the computers in the network to use my own DNS server in order to join my own domain (let's say, I use as DNS server 192.168.1.70) when I want to use internet on that computer, I can't because my DNS server can't resolve the others domain.

So is there any way to extend 8.8.8.8 DNS server or if my server can't resolve a hostname, delegate it to another DNS server?

Comment: Is recursion enabled on the DNS server? Can the DNS server access the internet? Windows DNS by default will use forwarders if configured to do so and will use the root hint servers with or without forwarders, so it should just work unless the DNS server doesn't have internet access or if recursion has been disabled.

Answer (score 0):

If you add DNS server role to your Windows 2012 server (Server Manager -> Local Server -> vpravo menu Manage -> Add roles and features -> Server roles -> DNS Server) and do not configure it at all, it will behave as cache DNS server - i.e. will get all unknown DNS info from the default machine's DNS server (e.g. 8.8.8.8). The only two things you need to care about are:

1. Have 53 TCP and UDP ports open in your firewall.
2. Have DNS server listening on the right IP address (either on ANY interface or in your case 192.168.1.70)